# AngularJS select option hide first empty option - with label animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a select box in my application which by default has a label on top like seen in the link below

[Default view of the select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnzKs.png)

When the user clicks the drop down, the label moves up with an animation and the options are visible.

[When select box opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoBxX.png)

What I am not able to do is to hide the first empty option when the select box is opened as it does not look good and also the select box value is required filed and I do not want to show a validation error message.

Please note I have added a class to make the label to stick to the top when a value is selected.

i.stack.imgur.com/DGlEw.png (Add https:// to this link)

Can someone help me with a way to hide the empty option without affecting the label animation?

Comment: it should be init default value for select tag

Comment: @HJz If I add a default option then it will overlap with my label when the select box is initially loaded. I do not want that to happen.